# For time adverbs, are particles instead of commas used in official (legal) writing?

Tags: particles, time

Even though *yesterday* is not an adverb, we say:

> I played golf yesterday.

only because the preposition, *on*, is dropped before *yesterday*. In that *on yesterday* becomes a prepositional phrase that modifies *played*:

> I played golf (on) yesterday.

That preposition dropping is a rule. What about Japanese sentences like:

> 昨日、ゴルフやった。

Grammatically, is there really a particle after *昨日* such as:

> 昨日 (では) ゴルフやった。
>   昨日 (に) ゴルフやった。

In speaking, you pause instead of saying the particle, but in official writing, are those possible particles after *昨日* written (instead of a comma)?

Of course, this is not limited to just *昨日* such as:

> 毎日、日本語を練習しています.
>   先週月曜日、出張した。
>   など...

In English legal contracts, every last preposition and comma are triple checked because they can make such a huge difference in any sort of dispute.

Now, Japanese commas seem to be void of specificity and thus open to "interpretation" by the counterparties / judge / arbiter, right? With big $ on the line, the counterparties must specify **exactly** what they are agreeing to, and you can't do that with commas???

Comment: I don't think 'on yesterday' is actually grammatical and if you look up 'yesterday' in a dictionary it's classified as an adverb in addition to a noun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you won't see any case particle after following words, official or not, as long as they're used to indicate the time when the sentence takes place *on/in*, because they are completely adverbial in this usage.

- 昨日, 今日, 明日 etc.
- 先週, 今週, 来週 etc.
- 先月, 今月, 来月 etc.
- 前期, 今期, 来期 etc.
- 去年, 今年, 来年 etc.
- 今朝, 明朝, 昨晩, 今晩, 今夜 etc.
- 毎日, 毎週, 毎月, 毎年 etc.

> 6時に荷物が届きそうだ。
> 夕方（に）荷物が届きそうだ。
> 今晩（× に）荷物が届きそうだ。
> 今日（× に）荷物が届きそうだ。
> 今週（× に）荷物が届きそうだ。

Of course, if you use those words in other ways, you must put right particles.

> 今日**で**仕事が終わる。 (*by* today)
> 今日**にも**荷物が届きそうだ。 (any day now)
> 今日（**も**／**は**）荷物が届きそうだ。 (particles other than case aren't affected)

Comment: 毎日とか毎年とかの「毎～」も加えられます？

Comment: @Chocolate なるほど～、ではそれも。ありがとうございます