# 明日来る ,明日に来る, 明日で来る

Tags: particles

good day everyone,

i'm just watching a basic Japanese video on YouTube (https://youtu.be/00kDTCOr1Do?t=391)

and 明日来る in the quick example was expressed as "will you come tomorrow".

I was wondering if in the same context you could use to two below, or is it completely wrong?

明日に来る,
明日で来る .

would i be able to interpret them as (tomorrow will you be here) & ( are you heading over tomorrow).

Thanks for your time, Shaun.

Comment: What have you learned about the particle で so far in your Japanese study?

Comment: while i will have to cover it again and again, at this moment when i see で
It's always with a nounでverb (carでtogo), so it's the action of going by the car to the ....

Comment: so i was curiouse if saying, 'tomorrow で to come' would be able to ... okay yeh, i see where this is going. I guess i might have been wondering if it was used in a non practicle sense, but i best not think too much into it.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32429/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct:

> (A-1) Will you come tomorrow?
>   (B-2) 明日｛あした｝来｛く｝る？

Incorrect:

> (A-2) Will you come **on** tomorrow?
>   (B-2) 明日｛あした｝**に**来｛く｝る？

Because tomorrow and 明日{あした} are <del>adjectives</del> adverbs not nouns.

Correct:

> (C-1) Will you come **on** the day one day after today?
>   (D-1) 今日｛きょう｝の次｛つぎ｝の日｛ひ｝**に**来｛く｝る？

Because "day" in "the day" and 日{ひ} in 次｛つぎ｝の日｛ひ｝ are nouns so you need a preposition **on** in (C-1) and a particle **に** in (D-1).

We don't say like (E) for (A-1).

> (E) 今日の次の日**で**来る？

So, 明日**に**来る, 明日**で**来る are both incorrect.

> would i be able to interpret them as (tomorrow will you be here) & ( are you heading over tomorrow).

My attempts are:
(F) Tomorrow will you be here? 明日ここにいますか？ or 明日はここにいますか？
(G) Are you heading over tomorrow? 明日来る？

Comment: `tomorrow and 明日 are adjectives` -- 「tomorrow」も「明日」も、adjectives (形容詞) ではないと思いますけど・・・ adverbs (副詞) と間違っていらっしゃいません？（一応、辞書には「今日」とか「明日」などは名詞で載ってるんですけどね・・・）

Comment: @Chocolate: 副詞はadverbですね。うっかり間違えました。訂正します。もちろん、今日も明日も名詞でもあることは承知です。tomorrowも同じですね。品詞が複数あって、その中で、ＯＰから提示されている文では副詞という意味です。あまり色々書くと複雑になるので説明を省略しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。