# Is the に time particle optional when talk about repeated action?

Tags: particle-に, て-form, time, formality

I have already learned about に time particle (in short: determines the action time if the time expression isn't relative). But I saw some text where dropped when used the まいとし, まいつき、まいにち etc.

For example:

> まいにち おちゃ を のんでいます。- I'm drinking tea every day.

Is this correct? Or should I use with the particle?:

> まいにち **に** おちゃ を のんでいます。- I'm drinking tea every day.

If the two sentence is correct then is the difference: the last sentence is more formal than first?

Comment: You say you saw sentences where に was dropped from 毎日 etc, but I wonder where you have seen sentences that included に?

Comment: So you mean: can I not use に with まいにち etc.?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32429/9831

Comment: That's ok: I cannot use にparticle with tomorrow, next week, last moth, next year etc because these relative time expressions. In my interpretation the relative time expressions are those time expressions which determine the date/time from the current time (now). For example if today is monday and I say tomorrow then tomorrow is tuesday. Or if today is sunday then tomorrow is monday. But the every day or every month etc always determines the same days, months and don't depend from the current time that's why I can use に particle with these. Or is this wrong?

Comment: I'm confident in saying that adding に is not usual for the way you are trying to use it. Whether it is strictly ungrammatical, I'm not so sure about, but I suspect so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, まいとし, まいつき, まいにち and so on never take に. You have to remember which word needs に and which word works on its own as an adverb. (In English, "every month" and so on don't need "in" or "on", so this should not be surprising.)