# Is using に with 先日 incorrect?

Tags: particles, particle-に

Bunpo-check keeps saying that the に in here is incorrect 先日に歩た時の、校長さんを見た
If it's so, please explain me why. Thanks

Comment: And does it say 歩**た** , 時**の** and 校長**さん** are all correct? 

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32429/7810